# Django model field default from model method

Tags: python, django, model, default

I want to give a model field default value from the a model method.

How can i do that ?

when i try this code

```
Class Person(models.Model):
    def create_id(self):
        return os.urandom(12).encode('hex')

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    id = models.CharField(max_length = 255,default = self.create_id)
```

I get NameError: name 'self' is not defined.

If i remove the 'self' i get that 'create_id' needs 1 parameter.

Comment: Does the id have to be unique? person_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True ) Just as an idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up doing this: (removing the self from both)

```
Class Person(models.Model):
    def create_id():
        return os.urandom(12).encode('hex')

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    id = models.CharField(max_length = 255,default = create_id)
```

it is working, but i am not sure if this is the best or the right way.

Comment: This *looks* good. I also wonder if this is a good *practice.*

Comment: How is this working? I think you're missing `self` as the first parameter of `create_id`, and call it like this: `self.create_id()` instead of `create_id`

Comment: @eugene it's not good practice in the sense that id's might not be unique, and I'd guess it's supposed to be.

Comment: odd that you can't use self to refer to a member funciton in a class.

Comment: It's a serialization issue for migrations

Answer (score 9):

You can define global method like this:

```
def create_id():
    return os.urandom(12).encode('hex')

Class Person(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
   id = models.CharField(max_length = 255,default = create_id)
```

Comment: i would like to make method of the class.

Comment: Usually if you need it to be on the class, that means you probably need other model attributes. the `.save()` method would be the best for this.